# Как узнать, имеет ли родитель второго уровня определенный класс?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
<div class="select form_select">
    <span>Прямая</span>
    <div class="select_list">
        <div>Прямая</div>
        <div>Угловая</div>
        <div>С островом</div>
        <div>П-образная</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как при клике на дочерний `div` блока с классом `.select_list` узнать, имеет ли родитель второго уровня `.select` класс `.form_select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, например:

```
$('.select.form_select .select_list > div').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('form_select')) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Или так, хотя тут проверка не такая строгая, как в задаче:

```
$('.select.form_select .select_list > div').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).closest('.form_select').length > 0) {
        ...
    }
});
```